# Displaying Devise User Name in a Different Model + Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, devise

I have a Reservations model which displays reservations made by a user from a Devise model.
I would like to display the name of the user who made the reservation.

I used <%= current_user.name %> but this just displays the name of the current user signed in and not the user which made the reservation. Any ideas on how to fix this?

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :remember_me
 has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Reservations model:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :user_id, :user_name, :start_time, :end_time, :project, :which_room
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Something along the lines of `reservation.user.name`.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that I had old data with no user name's associated so I just added <%= r.user.name if r.user.name != nil %> and it works.

Comment: It works locally but now I'm getting an error when deploying to heroku. I ran >heroku run rake db:migrate and >heroku restart but in my heroku logs, I get an error undefined method 'name' for nil:Nil Class